# Identity in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $x\cdot y=|x||y|\cos \theta.$

Tags: real-analysis

If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $$x\cdot y=|x||y|\cos \theta.$$

Can anyone show the full proof.

Comment: Sometimes, this is the definition of $\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it using the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Application_to_the_cosine_law).

Stop before the last statement on the link, apply the cosine rule, and then see that $$\vec a.\vec b=|a||b|\cos\theta$$.